# OpenCv Applying Filter on Circular Portion of Image

Tags: image, opencv, vision

Is there a simple way to apply a filter on a circular portion of an image in opencv, so that a central circle of the image could be unmodified and all other data outside of the circle blurred.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an inverted circular mask and then blur the whole image. After that, you copy only the desired portion of the blurred area back to the original image.

```
Mat mask(orig.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(255));
circle(mask, center, radius, Scalar(0));

Mat filtered;
filter2D(orig, filtered, ...);
filtered.copyTo(orig, mask);
```

Comment: can anyone convert this to python?